# Where to edit the app - in assets or in the main folder?

Tags: cordova

After adding a platform in `phonegap`, a folder created:

```
E:\projects\PhoneGap\app\platforms\android\assets\www .
```

Where should I keep editing my code, in this folder or in the main folder?

```
E:\projects\PhoneGap\app\www
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should definitely edit your code in the app/www folder. Otherwise your code in the app/platforms/android/assets/www folder will be overwritten if you execute:

```
phonegap run android
```